# Scan Bluetooth devices in android studio

Tags: android

I try to write a code from documentation but every time it asks for self-check permission and I did not get any device name
Help me to write a code to scan devices in the area

GitHub repositor link for my application
https://github.com/sachinraj0093/BluetoothAttendance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/bluetoothattendenceapplication/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

If your device running on Android 11 or lower, you need to check the Location is turned on. And in your code, you lack of calling discovery in case !mbluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering().

You can check returned value when call BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() to examine the status for start discovery action.